# Why can't I deploy Firebase Functions when importing a TypeScript interface from outside the functions folder?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My folder structure looks similar to this:

```
my-app/
├─ functions/
│  ├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ index.ts
│  │  ├─ testing.ts
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
├─ node_modules/
├─ src/
│  ├─ types.ts
│  ├─ index.css
│  ├─ index.ts
├─ package.json
├─ tsconfig.json
```

And I have a TypeScript interface declared in `my-app/src/types.ts` that I want to import it into `my-app/functions/src/testing.ts`.

But whenever I do that I cannot deploy functions to Firebase.

I am running firebase-tools 4.2 (the latest version) and I deploy using the command `firebase deploy --only functions`.

The deployment runs, there are no errors, but the Firebase Cloud Functions (such as my `helloWorld` example below) are never created.

Here is a reproduction of the problematic code:

**my-app/tsconfig.json**

```TypeScript
{
  "extends": "@quasar/app-vite/tsconfig-preset",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

**my-app/functions/tsconfig.json**

```TypeScript
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**my-app/src/types.ts**

```TypeScript
export interface MyTestInterface {
  text: string;
}
```

**my-app/functions/src/index.ts**

```TypeScript
export { helloWorld } from './testing';
```

**my-app/functions/src/testing.ts**

```TypeScript
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { MyTestInterface } from '../../src/types'; // <--- Whenever I import this Firebase Cloud Functions are not created
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const foo: MyTestInterface = {
    text: 'Hello World!'
  };
  functions.logger.info(foo.text);
  res.status(200).send('All good baby');
  return;
});
```

Is it possible to import an interface from outside the `functions` folder as shown above?

If that is possible, why does Firebase fail to create the function?

One solution that works is to create a second version of `MyTestInterface` inside the `functions` folder (i.e. `my-app/functions/src/types.ts`) but that causes problems if both interfaces are not kept identical.

Comment: Where is your `tsconfig.json` file and what sources does it specify?

Comment: @Phil I have one in `my-app/tsconfig.json` and another in `my-app/functions/tsconfig.json`. I have updated the question to show the location and content of both. Not sure what you mean by sources though?